# how to open an app using adb commands if the app is not present in the home screen?

Tags: android, automated-tests

actually I'm trying to launch amazon prime app using adb commands in python ,but I'm not able to open the app if it is present in the device ,its getting opened only if the app is in home screen .I have to open the app where ever its present on my device???please help me out.

I'm trying in win 10

Answer (score 0):

you can use "am start -n" commands.
`adb shell am start -n com.test/com.test.TestActivity`